# Jquery - converting type before splitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, types, split

I have this html-snippet:

```
<div id="container" data-id="20.20"></div>
```

Using this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("div#container").click(function() {

        var foo = $(this).data("id");
        console.log( typeof foo ) // returns "number"

        foo = String(foo);
        console.log(foo) // returns "string"

    });
});
```

So my situation:

I need the variable "foo" to be string, because i want to use the Jquery-split-function.

My questions:

1. Why "foo" is first returned as a "number", i thought it is directly saved as a "string" ?
2. Is my way a good one to change the the type of the variable or should i use an other way ?

Comment: Consider using .attr('data-id') if you want the unparsed value.

Comment: you gave best answer here. thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

[`jQuery.data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) tries to guess the datatype of the data attribute:

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value
>   (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null). A value
>   is only converted to a number if doing so doesn't change the value's
>   representation. For example, "1E02" and "100.000" are equivalent as
>   numbers (numeric value 100) but converting them would alter their
>   representation so they are left as strings. The string value "100" is
>   converted to the number 100.
>
> [...]
>
> To retrieve the value's attribute as a string without any attempt to
>   convert it, use the attr() method.

Note that according to the rules above, the value `20.2` will be converted to a number but `20.20` **will not be converted**.

Having said that, use `.attr()` to grab the value without conversion. Or, use any of the following methods to convert a number (or just about any object) to string:

```
expr.toString()
String(expr)
"" + expr
```

Answer (score 0):

To separate the decimal and whole number part, you could force the number to be an integer using the bitwise `|` to drop the decimals. Then subtract it from the original to get the decimal:

```
var foo = $(this).data("id"); //20.20
var integer = foo | 0;        //20
var decimal = foo - integer;  //0.20
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it comes back as a string initially: http://jsbin.com/dobas/1/

Maybe you are setting the data with a number?  For example:

```
$el.data('id', 20.20);
```

If so, change this to set a string, and perhaps it will come back as a string:

```
$el.data('id', '20.20');
```